# Attach Database Backup file in E-Mail send not working

Tags: php, phpmailer, database-backups

I am using following code to take backup of my mysql database.

With this code, a file is created and get saved in same folder where this script is kept. It is working perfectly.

I am trying to email this file using phpmailer. But I am stucked as **no file is getting attached to receiving email**. (email is delivered without attached file...)

Basic code is taken from https://write.corbpie.com/php-pdo-mysql-backup-script-with-compression-option/

Help is appreciated... and thank you in advanced...

**Backup creating code part is as follows :**

```
<?php
 include_once("../../include/mysqli_constants.php");
 require("../../PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php");

 $db_server         = constant('HST');                                            
 $db_name           = constant('DBN');
 $db_user           = constant('USR');
 $db_pass           = constant('PWD');

 $site_url          = constant('FILEROOT');
 $from_email        = constant('FROMEMAIL');
 $from_name         = constant('FROMNAME');
 $mail_to1          = 'mypersonal@gmail.com';
 $mail_to1_name     = 'Dr Manish Joshi';
 $mail_to2          = '';
 $mail_to2_name     = '';

 $save_dir          = './';
 $file_name_prefix  = 'my_website_';

 $date = strtolower(date('d_F_Y_H_i_s_A'));

 /* Do NOT EDIT BELOW */

$backup_config = array(
'DB_HOST' => $db_server,////Database hostname
'DB_NAME' => $db_name,//Database name to backup
'DB_USERNAME' => $db_user,//Database account username
'DB_PASSWORD' => $db_pass,//Database account password
'INCLUDE_DROP_TABLE' => false,//Include DROP TABLE IF EXISTS
'SAVE_DIR' => '',//Folder to save file in
'SAVE_AS' => $file_name_prefix,//Prepend filename
'APPEND_DATE_FORMAT' => 'Y_m_d_H_i_s',//Append date to file name
'TIMEZONE' => 'Asia/Kolkata',//Timezone for date format
'COMPRESS' => true,//Compress into gz otherwise keep as .sql
 );

echo backupDB($backup_config);
```

**Email sending part is as follows :**

```
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsHTML(true); 
$mail->Host = constant('EMAILHOST'); 
$mail->AddAddress(''.$mail_to1.'', ''.$mail_to1_name.'');
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = constant('SMTPAuth');
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; 
$mail->Mailer = "smtp"; 
$mail->SMTPDebug = constant('SMTPDEBUG');
$mail->Username = constant('SMTPUSERNAME');
$mail->Password = constant('SMTPPASSWORD');
$mail->Port = 587; 

$mail->From = constant('FROMEMAIL');
$mail->FromName = constant('FROMNAME');
           
$mail->WordWrap = 50; 
$mail->Subject = '['.$from_name.'] Cron Backup MySQL On - ' . $date;
$mail->Body    = $save_string.' File is attached via cron';
$mail->AddAttachment($save_string);

  if (!$mail->AddAttachment($save_string)) {   
    echo 'Erreur : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo . "\n";
    $mail->Body .= "\n" . 'Erreur : ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
  }

  if (!$mail->Send()){
    echo 'Message could not be sent. <p>';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
}
echo 'Message has been sent';
```

**Function to create database backup** is as follows and it is working OK and creating db backup and saving file in folder.

```
/* FUNCTION Starts */
 function backupDB(array $config): string {
   $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['DB_HOST']};dbname={$config['DB_NAME']}; charset=utf8", $config['DB_USERNAME'], $config['DB_PASSWORD']);
   $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_NATURAL);

   date_default_timezone_set($config['TIMEZONE']);
   $do_compress = $config['COMPRESS'];

if ($do_compress) {
    $save_string = $config['SAVE_AS'] . $config['SAVE_DIR'] . date($config['APPEND_DATE_FORMAT']) . '.sql.gz';
    $zp = gzopen($save_string, "a9");
} else {
    $save_string = $config['SAVE_AS'] . $config['SAVE_DIR'] . date($config['APPEND_DATE_FORMAT']) . '.sql';
    $handle = fopen($save_string, 'a+');
}

//array of all database field types which just take numbers
$numtypes = array('tinyint', 'smallint', 'mediumint', 'int', 'bigint', 'float', 'double', 'decimal', 'real');

$return = "";
$return .= "CREATE DATABASE `{$config['DB_NAME']}`;\n";
$return .= "USE `{$config['DB_NAME']}`;\n";

//get all tables
$pstm1 = $db->query('SHOW TABLES');
while ($row = $pstm1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
    $tables[] = $row[0];
}

//cycle through the table(s)
foreach ($tables as $table) {
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM $table");
    $num_fields = $result->columnCount();
    $num_rows = $result->rowCount();

    if ($config['INCLUDE_DROP_TABLE']) {
        $return .= 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `' . $table . '`;';
    }

    //table structure
    $pstm2 = $db->query("SHOW CREATE TABLE $table");
    $row2 = $pstm2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
    $ifnotexists = str_replace('CREATE TABLE', 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS', $row2[1]);
    $return .= "\n\n" . $ifnotexists . ";\n\n";

    if ($do_compress) {
        gzwrite($zp, $return);
    } else {
        fwrite($handle, $return);
    }
    $return = "";

    //insert values
    if ($num_rows) {
        $return = 'INSERT INTO `' . $table . '` (';
        $pstm3 = $db->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table");
        $count = 0;
        $type = array();

        while ($rows = $pstm3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
            if (stripos($rows[1], '(')) {
                $type[$table][] = stristr($rows[1], '(', true);
            } else {
                $type[$table][] = $rows[1];
            }

            $return .= "`" . $rows[0] . "`";
            $count++;
            if ($count < ($pstm3->rowCount())) {
                $return .= ", ";
            }
        }

        $return .= ")" . ' VALUES';

        if ($do_compress) {
            gzwrite($zp, $return);
        } else {
            fwrite($handle, $return);
        }
        $return = "";
    }
    $counter = 0;
    while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM)) {
        $return = "\n\t(";

        for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {

            if (isset($row[$j])) {

                //if number, take away "". else leave as string
                if ((in_array($type[$table][$j], $numtypes)) && (!empty($row[$j]))) {
                    $return .= $row[$j];
                } else {
                    $return .= $db->quote($row[$j]);
                }
            } else {
                $return .= 'NULL';
            }
            if ($j < ($num_fields - 1)) {
                $return .= ',';
            }
        }
        $counter++;
        if ($counter < ($result->rowCount())) {
            $return .= "),";
        } else {
            $return .= ");";
        }
        if ($do_compress) {
            gzwrite($zp, $return);
        } else {
            fwrite($handle, $return);
        }
        $return = "";
    }
    $return = "\n\n-- ------------------------------------------------ \n\n";
    if ($do_compress) {
        gzwrite($zp, $return);
    } else {
        fwrite($handle, $return);
    }
    $return = "";
}

$error1 = $pstm2->errorInfo();
$error2 = $pstm3->errorInfo();
$error3 = $result->errorInfo();
echo $error1[2];
echo $error2[2];
echo $error3[2];

if ($do_compress) {
    gzclose($zp);
} else {
    fclose($handle);
}

return "{$config['DB_NAME']} saved as $save_string";
}
?>
```

Comment: Break your code into multiple parts. It sounds like your backup is working fine, so make a function (or class or whatever) that does that, and reports the file(s) that it created. Then make another function/class that does the email stuff. Lastly, make a final bit of code that calls the backup stuff and reports it to the email stuff. Then you can just post the “email stuff” portion here so that we can focus on helping you. Otherwise, that’s a lot of code for us to weed through.

Comment: You appear to be making `$save_string` inside of the backup function, but it gets thrown away once the function gets done. You need to either return it from the function and have the caller keep track of it (preferred) or use a global state (usually discouraged).

Comment: Ok thanks..... any code sample please for to  return it from the function and have the caller keep track of it ?

Comment: Instead of `echo backupDB($backup_config);` which echoes and throws away, you can use something like `$save_string = backupDB($backup_config);`. You can then `echo $save_string` if you really want. If your PHPMailer is converted to a wrapper function, you’d pass that as a parameter. If it isn’t a function, then it should have access to that variable because they are in the same scope.

Comment: What the others said, and also you’re trying to attach the same file twice with unnecessary duplicate calls to addAttachment

Comment: Sending a database backup via email is a bad idea... size of the backup file might be huge, and the datbase may contain sensitive data (email is a insecure communication channel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have edited this code and now it is working...

Edited code kept on github...

https://github.com/vaidyamanishjoshi/db-backup-with-pdo-and-email-it